# DropdownList in ASP.NET MVC 3 can't populate thousands of records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How to make a dropdownlist in *asp.net mvc 3* handle a thousands of records?

I tried to populate a it with a 10,000 number of records but it won't work.
Instead it will refresh the page.

By the way, I'm using Entity Framework `DBContext`.

Need some help on how to fix this..

Thank you.

Comment: A dropdown list with 10,000 entries is completely unusable.  You should change your interface and use something like a text input with constrained autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I you have 10k items in your drop down list, you are better off not using a dropdown list. Use something faster / leaner like an autocomplete box or a search field.